# How to convert collection to array without creating a new array?

Tags: java, collections

Suppose I have a collection (LinkedList).

```
Collection<String> list = new LinkedList<>();

for (int i = 0; i < 1_000_000; i++) {
    String randomString = RandomStringUtils.random(i);
    list.add(randomString);
}

Object[] objects = list.toArray();
```

When I invoke `toArray` method if forces my app to create a new array. For example in LinkedList implementation of `toArray` looks like this:

```
public Object[] toArray() {
    Object[] result = new Object[size];
    int i = 0;
    for (Node<E> x = first; x != null; x = x.next)
        result[i++] = x.item;
    return result;
}
```

Is it possible to retrieve an array from the collection without allocation a new memory for an array?

Comment: If you don't create a new array, where do you want the elements to be stored?

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to retrieve an array from the collection without allocation a **new** memory for an array?

(Emphasis mine)

You can reuse a pre-allocated array:

```
Object[] arr = new Object[1_000_000];
```

and then use the same array multiple times by invoking the [`toArray(T[])`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#toArray(T[])) overload, avoiding reallocation of the array:

```
list.toArray(arr);
```

The caveat is that the `arr` has to be at least the size of the collection; otherwise, a new array of the same element type will be allocated and returned:

```
Object[] correctSizedArray = list.toArray(wronglySizedArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

This will only create a new array, if the parameter array is not big enough to hold all entries:

```
String[] strings = new String[1000];
String[] result = list.toArray(strings);
```